# Keyboard Slideshows - select only screen viewed one

Tags: html, css, slideshow

I am working on my portfolio right now and therefore I want to include several slideshows which are controlled via keyboard. I am working with this code right now and the slideshow works fine. My problem is now that both slideshows are selected at the same time and not only the one which is visible on screen.

How do I activate / deactivate the slideshow which the user sees?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">

<head>
  <title></title>
<style type="text/css">

#SS {
  position:relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top:100px;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
}

#SS2 {
  position:relative;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  top:100px;
  width:600px;
  height:600px;
}

</style></head>

<body>
<input type="button" name="" value="Back" onmouseup="Slideshow.next('SS',-1);" />
<input type="button" name="" value="Next" onmouseup="Slideshow.next('SS',1);" />

 <div id="SS" >
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_01.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_04.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_05.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_06.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_07.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_08.jpg" class="thumb" />

 </div>





<input type="button" name="" value="Back" onmouseup="Slideshow.next('SS2',-1);" />
<input type="button" name="" value="Next" onmouseup="Slideshow.next('SS2',1);" />

 <div id="SS2" >
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_01.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_04.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_05.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_06.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_07.jpg" class="thumb" />
  <br />
  <img width="600" height="600" src="http://www.ignant.de/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/Witchoria_Landscapes_08.jpg" class="thumb" />

 </div>




<script type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/

var Slideshow={

 init:function(id){
  var obj=document.getElementById(id),imgs=obj.getElementsByTagName('IMG'),z0=0,clone;
  Slideshow[id]={};
  Slideshow[id].obj=obj;
  Slideshow[id].ary=[];
  Slideshow[id].cnt=0;
  for (;z0<imgs.length;z0++){
   imgs[z0].style.position='absolute';
   imgs[z0].style.left=(z0>0?-3000:(obj.offsetWidth-imgs[z0].width)/2)+'px';
   imgs[z0].style.top=(obj.offsetHeight-imgs[z0].height)/2+'px';
   clone=document.createElement('IMG');
   clone.src=imgs[z0].src;
   clone.style.position='absolute';
   clone.style.zIndex='101';
   clone.style.left='-3000px';
   document.body.appendChild(clone);
   Slideshow[id].ary[z0]=[imgs[z0],clone];
  // Slideshow.addevt(imgs[z0],'mouseover','pop',id,z0);
   Slideshow.addevt(clone,'mouseout','hide');
  }
  Slideshow.addevt(document,'keyup','keycode',id);
  Slideshow.lst=clone;

 },

 next:function(id,ud){
  Slideshow.hide();
  var oop=Slideshow[id],obj=oop.obj,cnt=oop.cnt+ud,lgth=oop.ary.length-1,img;
  oop.ary[oop.cnt][0].style.left='-3000px';
  cnt=cnt<0?lgth:cnt==lgth?0:cnt;
  img=oop.ary[cnt][0];
  img.style.left=(obj.offsetWidth-img.width)/2+'px';
  img.style.top=(obj.offsetHeight-img.height)/2+'px';
  oop.cnt=cnt;
 },

 keycode:function(id,nu,e){
  Slideshow.hide();
  var kk;
  if (e.which){
   kk=e.which;
  }
  else {
   kk=e.keyCode;
  }
  if (kk==37||kk==39){
   Slideshow.next(id,kk==37?-1:1);
  }
 },

 pop:function(id,nu){
  Slideshow.hide();
  var oop=Slideshow[id],pos=Slideshow.pos(oop.obj),clone=oop.ary[nu][1];
  clone.style.left=(oop.obj.offsetWidth-clone.width)/2+pos[0]+'px';
  clone.style.top=(oop.obj.offsetHeight-clone.height)/2+pos[1]+'px';
  Slideshow.lst=clone;
 },

 hide:function(){
  Slideshow.lst.style.left='-3000px';
 },

 pos:function(obj){
  var rtn=[0,0];
  while(obj){
   rtn[0]+=obj.offsetLeft;
   rtn[1]+=obj.offsetTop;
   obj=obj.offsetParent;
  }
  return rtn;
 },

 addevt:function(o,t,f,id,p){
  if (o.addEventListener) o.addEventListener(t,function(e){ return Slideshow[f](id,p,e);}, false);
  else if (o.attachEvent) o.attachEvent('on'+t,function(e){ return Slideshow[f](id,p,e); });
 }
}

Slideshow.init('SS')
Slideshow.init('SS2')

/*]]>*/
</script></body>

</html>
```

Comment: You can check to see if the slideshow is in view by comparing the bottom of the viewport to the bottom of your slideshow

Comment: ie -- if (window.pageYOffset+window.offsetHeight<obj.offsetTop+obj.offsetHeight) obj is in view!

Comment: Thanks. Do I need to put that if-loop around Slideshow.init('SS')
Slideshow.init('SS2')?